# Compile and link many source files from different folders with g++ and make

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

What is proper way to compile and link many .cpp files which comes from different folders into one exacutable using makefile?

For example I have following file structure:

```
./Foo/Wow/Bar/example1.cpp
./Foo/Bar/example2.cpp
./Foo/example3.cpp
./main.cpp
```

Now I want to compile and link all of these files into one executable. Which is proper way to do this with makefile?

Thanks,
S.

Comment: You absolutely do not need to use shared objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one correct way to do this.

One possibility would be for to separate the code into libraries, one per subdirectory. Each of those libraries would have its own makefile.

Then the project root would have a makefile that invoked make recursively to ensure those libraries were all up to date, then used the libraries to build the main executable(s).

Others object (sometimes vociferously) to that whole notion. It might be all right to use existing libraries (and their existing makefiles), but they often object to the basic idea of turning code in the subdirectories into libraries, just for the sake of having a single result file to link into the final executable (OTOH, few seem to have a solid explanation of why you'd put code into a subdirectory to start with, if it didn't embody some logical concept that would probably qualify it as a meaningful library).

Comment: `g++ -c $(shell find ./Foo -name '*.cpp')` Is this good idea to start with?

Comment: @SeCorp: at least generally, I'd say no. In a lot of cases, you'll have things like unit test code and localized/ported versions of code, so no one build will include all the code in all the subdirectories. At best, attempting to compile them all will waste time. In many more cases, it'll outright fail, even though building the code you need could/would succeed.